# Finding all solutions of an equation of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Suppose $x\ge0, y\in (0,1)$ and define $z=\frac{ye^x}{ye^x+1-y}$ and consider the following equation,  $$\frac{ye^x+1-y}{e^{xz}}=1.$$

Now of course $x=0$ is a solution of this equation, but I am interested if there are other solutions. I tried to consider the right handside as a function and show that it is strict monoton to conclude that there are no other solutions, but this was not fruitful.

> Does anyone have an idea how to show that this functions has no other solutions than $x=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $e^x=t$ then $z=\frac{yt}{yt+1-y}$.

If $x>0$ then $t>1$, $1>z>y$.

Equation becomes $yt+1-y=t^z$.

Putting it in $z=\frac{yt}{yt+1-y}$ one can get
$$z=\frac{yt}{t^z} \Rightarrow y=zt^{z-1}$$

Putting it in $yt+1-y=t^z$ one can get

$$zt^z+1-zt^{z-1}=t^z\Rightarrow (z-1)t^z-zt^{z-1}=-1\Rightarrow (z-1)(t-1)t^{z-1}=t^{z-1}-1$$

If $t>1$, $z<1$ then left hand side is negative, right hand side is positive.

Comment: $t^{z-1}=e^{{x}^{z-1}}=e^{xz-x}$ is not bigger than $1$ so why is the right hand side positive?

Comment: I think this answer does not solve the problem at all..